# Toolbar overlap with status bar in android

Tags: android, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have implement a collapsingToolbarLayout with a toolbar. the problem is that toolbar is overlapping below status bar. I have read other related problem **( android:fitsSystemWindows="true")** on stackoverflow but some thing is wrong and they are not working in my problem.

here is my activity xml :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

  <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="16dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="0dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="40dp"
         app:collapsedTitleGravity="start"
       app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/colapsedTextAprearance"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/expandedTextAprearance"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
 >
   <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subtitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            />
  <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/peyvtoolbar"

        />

  </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and peyvtoolbar.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
    >


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

[image]

Comment: You went a little overboard with the triple nested `android:fitsSystemWindows` try only one in the CoordinatorLayout. For some details on that attribute, you can read  https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec#.mdweantq7

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I removed two other and nothing changed

Comment: What image are you showing here? Because that looks like an ImageView, but you only have a Textview in the CollapsingToolbar

Comment: Also, maybe I was wrong initially, this post does show all the components have the fitsSystemWindows.  http://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/

Comment: yes my friend, I used that components, but I don't know what cause my problem when the example there is ok, I am studying the link you give in first comment